# Is there a way to tell cppcheck to ignore a macro (or properly expand it)?

Tags: c++, c++03, cppcheck

I have the following syntax for run-time type identification:

```
if RTTI_FUNC( c, short, myFunc );
else if RTTI_FUNC( c, float, myFunc );
else if RTTI_FUNC( c, complex<short>, myFunc );
else if RTTI_FUNC( c, complex<float>, myFunc );
```

where RTTI_FUNC is defined in another file as

```
#define RTTI_FUNC(in,type,func) \
    ( dynamic_cast<MyClass< type >* >(in) ) \
        func( *(reinterpret_cast<MyClass< type >* >(in)) )
```

When I run

```
cppcheck . --force --enable=all -q
```

it reports

> (error) syntax error

for the *if RTTI_FUNC( c, short, myFunc );* line

The error is a false positive. Is there any way to ignore it or suppress it other than using an inline suppression? Possibly with a rule or regex?

Alternatively, is it possible to expand the macro to correct the false positive?

Comment: Wow, what the hell is a `reinterpret_cast` doing here? You can simply do `if(auto p = dynamic_cast<...>(...)) func(*p)`...

Comment: Unfortunately, no c++11 support.

Comment: Just replace `auto` with the actual type. Declarations inside `if`s are part of the language since the beginning.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for the suggestion. Admittedly, I didn't read your comment very carefully.

Comment: Solved my problem by bulk replacing invalid values in commands.json file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-I <path/to/include/dir>` which will allow cppcheck to expand the macro